# Getting error while writing stream on android 14 using react-native-blob-util

Tags: android, react-native, blob, android-permissions

I am trying to write stream using the following code below

```
let {dirs} = ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs;
const dirToSave = Platform.OS == 'ios' ? dirs.DocumentDir : dirs.DownloadDir;

let PATH_TO_FILE = dirs.DownloadDir + '/' + json.fileName.replace(/ /g, '') + '.pdf';

ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.writeStream(
  PATH_TO_FILE,
  // encoding, should be one of `base64`, `utf8`, `ascii`
  'base64',
  // should data append to existing content ?
  true
)
.then(stream => Promise.all([
    stream.write(json.fileContent)
]))
// Use array destructuring to get the stream object from the first item of the array we get from Promise.all()
.then(([stream]) => {
  stream.close()
  ToastAndroid.show('File saved in downloads', ToastAndroid.LONG)
})
.catch(console.error)
```

It was working fine on android 14 but i test this on android 9 it is not writing the file so i found out that i need run time permission to write the file, so i just added and it starts working fine then but for android 14 it stops writing the file and start giving me the following error

```
{ [Error: File '/storage/emulated/0/Download/sTitleENFinal.pdf' does not exist and could not be created]
       code: 'ENOENT',
       line: 106879,
       column: 30,
       sourceURL: 'http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.package.name&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true' }
```